High heat non-toxic caulk for dishwasher interior
The detergent dispenser in my stainless-steel interior dishwasher is leaching rust. What non-toxic caulk can be used around the dispenser to contain the rust?

Buy a new dishwasher before you have a leak and serious water damage.

Please post a picture of the issue. Maybe there's a better solution than caulk.

There is no caulking solution for this. The interior of the dishwasher is expected to be wet and the detergents water soluble. If you claim the interior is stainless steel and you have rusting parts, then there are some non stainless parts that are rusting or the stainless steel is the wrong type for this purpose.

This is an XY question with no good answer. If your dishwasher experiences "high heat" something's gone terribly wrong.

Silicone caulk is available in non-toxic formulations (look for labeling along the lines of "safe for incidental food contact" - some formulations are NOT, due to mildewcides, etc.) and is high temperature compatible.
However: That does not mean it will fix a dishwasher that's rusting out. Generally you need to replace the rusting part, hopefully with a part that's better designed for the job. Slapping caulk on or around it is unlikely to be a lasting fix.

Thanks for answers. The dishwasher walls are fine and rust scrubs off. There must be a non stainless-steel screw or part holding the soap dispenser to the door. I'm looking at food contact grade RTV silicone, but some say the acetic acid cure is corrosive to metal. Ideal solution would be to dismantle the door and replace the soap dispenser .

Stainless Steel is not affected by at acetic acid. And that will be a temporary effect anyway, gone once it's finished curing.

Backyard mechanics use RTV silicone on a lot of metals that are not stainless steel.  Corrosion in engines is not good, but quite a few have some silicone on them.  It does tend to clear up sinus
